# Issues with Code Signing Certificate

Tags: windows, visual-studio, firefox, x509certificate, code-signing

My boss recently purchased a code signing certificate from Comodo. I now have the task of making it work in VS2013 using Strong Name Key signing and perhaps as a post-build event, too. He did the whole purchasing process on the same machine (Windows 8.1 64-bit laptop) and using the same browser (Firefox 59.0.1 64-bit). I have gone to the Menu > Options > Privacy & Security > View Certificates > Your Certificates screen in Firefox, and selected the cert that was just purchased. I then clicked the "Backup" button, named it something generic, like companyCert.p12 (I don't get any other choice or settings but .p12), clicked the "Save" button, and entered a 16-character alphanumeric (caps and lowercase) password, and clicked the "OK" button. I got the popup saying that the export was successful.

When I try to import that .p12, or the extension-renamed .pfx, file into the local user's Personal or Trusted Publishers certificate store through mmc (even tried certmgr.msc just for kicks), I get:

> The password you entered is incorrect.

When I try to build my assemblies in VS using the .p12 file to Strong Name Key sign them, I get:

> The key file 'absolute\path\to\cert\companyCert.p12' does not contain a public/private key pair.

When I try to do the same thing but renaming the extension to .pfx, I am prompted for the password, so I input that, and I get:

> An error occurred during encode or decode operation.

So I then tried to import the .p12/.pfx using the command prompt (running as administrator) and CertUtil using the following line:

```
certutil -importPFX -user "absolute\path\to\cert\companyCert.p12" AT_SIGNATURE
```

and I was prompted for the password, which I input, and got:

> CertUtil: -importPFX command FAILED: 0x80092002 (-2146885630 CRYPT_E_BAD_ENCODE)
>
> CertUtil: An error occurred during encode or decode operation.

for both .p12 and .pfx.

I've tried all of these several times just in case I did something wrong with the password or something. I've tried going back into the Firefox certificates and instead of clicking on the "Backup"

button in the Your Certificates screen, clicking on the code signing certificate, and clicking "View..." That takes me to the Certificate Viewer window, where I click on the Details tab and click the

"Export" button. There, I am given the choice of X.509 Certificates:

> PEM (.crt/.pem, both with or without chain)
>
> DER (.der without chain)
>
> and PKCS#7 (.p7c with or without chain)

I did all but .der when trying to do the code signing, but to no avail. I was able to import some of them into the local user's Personal and Trusted Publisher stores, but I was unable to get any of

them to work in VS for Strong Name Key signing.

As I understand it, I need to be able to get the private/public key certificate in the local store on the OS level, not just Firefox's browser level, and then I should be able to export how I need to. Is that correct? If it's not, please, someone tell me what I can do to get this to work.

Comment: what does `certutil -dump path\pfxfile.pfx` command return?

Comment: @Crypt32 I got: `An error occurred during encode or decode operation. 0x80092002 (-2146885630 CRYPT_E_BAD_ENCODE) CertUtil: -dump command FAILED: 0x80092002 (-2146885630 CRYPT_E_BAD_ENCODE) CertUtil: An error occurred during encode or decode operation.` So basically the same thing as before.

Comment: This means that your exported certificate content is malformed.

Comment: Argh. Thanks. I'll just see if I can have it replaced through another browser since their support team is blaming Firefox for the malformation.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I could successfully import the .pfx file in my Desktop running Windows 10, but when I tried to import the certificate in the server running Windows Server 2016 I received the error **"The password you entered is incorrect"**.

To solve the problem:

1. Remove the certificate from my windows (using Management Console / Certificates)
2. Import the original .pfx certificate to my Desktop Computer
3. Export the certificate (using Management Console / Certificates)

**The trick is:**

When exporting the certificate, select the encryption "TripleDES-SHA1".

Comment: A similar error message occurs from signtool.exe "the specified pfx password is not correct" - and the fix is the same, noticed on Windows Server 2016 version (1607 LTS channel). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded - **DigiCertUtil** - and manually installed the certificate with this tool, and it worked perfectly! 
https://www.digicert.com/util/

I managed to re-export the file and use the certUtil.exe with -importPFX.

Initially i used the digicert utility to install the certificate on one machine and add it to the store.
Then i exported it from the google chrome browser to a new .pfx file. (Settings > manage certificates > export)
And voila all of sudden the file was no longer corrupted and could be used with the certUtil.exe

I saw a post where the Comodo Support Team blamed Firefox for the issue, which made me wonder if chrome could export after the use of DigiCertUtil.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, when I exported the Signing Certificate from Firefox somehow the password didnt opening it after exporting. The DigiCertUtil COULD open it with the password and when you re-export with this utility the password works correctly. Weird.